# Core Data causes exception in endUpdates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app that is using Core Data to drive a `UITableView` with sections. It uses the standard `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` implementation that all the sample projects use. However, occasionally, but not reliably, calling `[self.tableView endUpdates]` throws the following exception:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 3 into section 1, but there are only 3 rows in section 1 after the update with userInfo (null)
```

After that the table view only has the cells that were visible at the time and empty space (but still scrollable) everywhere else. Nothing fixes it but restarting the app. I'm sure the app would crash except that `NSFetchedResultsController` is catching the exception.

After the app restarts, the data that caused the callbacks comes right up. And sure enough, there are only 3 rows in section 1 (or whatever the exception says). **So why the hell would Core Data be telling me to insert a row that doesn't exist?**

```
- (void)reloadFetch
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        TULogError(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        [[TCCacheController sharedController] clearData];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"FeedItem"];
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city = %@", [TCCity currentCity]];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"updatedAt" ascending:NO] ];
        fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[
                                                            @"user",
                                                            @"responses",
                                                            ];

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                        managedObjectContext:[TCCacheController sharedController].mainContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"day"
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        [self reloadFetch];
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        } case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        } case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        } case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove: {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I was adding my own custom section to the results returned from the NSFetchedResultsController. In doing so I had to make sure to adjust index paths when managing the returned results. I had missed handling the index path in didChangeObject method.

I implemented changing the index paths in a very brute force approach but while hunting for this problem I found a very helpful and more elegant solution in this SO post: [NSFetchedResultsController prepend a row or section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965098/nsfetchedresultscontroller-prepend-a-row-or-section) (see JosehpH's answer).

Comment: I've made that mistake before as well, but I'm not doing that here. The sections and rows map directly from CD.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the tableViewSection hard coded like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
//return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

That fixed it for me.