# Adding a new row in a NSFetchedResultsController managed UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm implementing a UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController.

```
# D5ProductViewController.h

@interface D5ProductViewController : D5ViewControllerAbstract <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) D5Product *product;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

- (IBAction)addVariantTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

```
# D5ProductViewController.m

@interface D5ProductViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation D5ProductViewController

- (void)viewLoad {
    NSError *error;
    [self.fetcedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    if (error) {
        [self.alerts showError:[error localizedDescription]
                               :@"Error"];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Properties

@synthesize managedObjectContext; // The context is passed from a parent view.
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Variant"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price"
                                                               ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"productId = '%@' AND isMaster = 0", self.product.identifier];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(D5VariantTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                 withObject:(D5Variant *)[controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(D5VariantTableViewCell *)cell
           withObject:(D5Variant *)variant {
    cell.variant = variant;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSourceDelegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    D5VariantTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:D5VariantCellReusableIdentifier
                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
    D5Variant *variant = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.variant = variant;
    cell.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)addVariantTapped:(id)sender {
    NSEntityDescription *variantEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Variant"
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    D5Variant *variant = [[D5Variant alloc] initWithEntity:variantEntityDescription
                        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    variant.productId = self.product.identifier;
    variant.price = [self.product.master price];
    variant.weight = [self.product.master weight];

    [variant markAsInserted];

    NSError *error;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

If I understand correctly, having implemented `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath` will cause UITableView to ask for a cell for the inserted row, which is configured with the object at the given `indexPath` from the `fetchedResultsController`.

The thing is that `controller:didChangeObject...newIndexPath` is never called when a new object is inserted in the `managedObjectContext`.

What am I missing? Do I need to call `managedObjectContext`'s save method and then `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That may help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604410/add-extra-row-to-a-uitableview-managed-by-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: I already gave it a roll, but that's not the case. Silly me, I just didn't set the UITableView's delegate `self.tableView.delegate = self;` and that was it.

Comment: .... that happens...:)

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I forgot to set the UITableView's delegate:

The `viewDidLoad` method, besides setting the bindings, was just performing the fetch. Adding `self.tableView.delegate = self;` fixed the problem, BUT, isn't it enough setting the `dataSource` outlet in the IB? Which I already did. Why did I need to set the `UITableView`'s delegate manually? In the case of the `NSFetchedResultsController` it needs to be set manually, but isn't it the purpose of the UITableView object having that outlet to just wire it up to the delegate object?

Anyways, setting `self.tableView.delegate = self;` fixed the problem.

Comment: A `UITableViewController` automatically sets the delegate and data source of its `tableView` to `self`. However, it seems that you have a `UIViewController` subclass with your own `tableView` property. That's why you have to set it yourself.